Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync. Firebase error
Hello I've tried connecting to firebase but the it shows "Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync."
I tried changing the project structure and removing some dependecies but it still isn't working
Here is my app gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.onlinepetshop"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.onlinepetshop"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding=true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")

    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktv:1.4.0")

    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1")
    implementation("com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:5.0")

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
}

Here is my project gradle
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.google.services)
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
}

any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Can you show us the dependencies that are related to Firebase?

Have you followed Firebase's integration guide for Android?

Hello and thank you for answering, I tried using the Firebase using the Firebase Assistant in the Firebase Integration guide and then clicking Connect to Firebase but this error is showing up.

I guess I am late to reply now
But next time you should add the Firebase dependencies from the Tools>Firebase or Assistant in the Right tab as Firebase version dependencies are some critical error which is not displayed properly in LOGS

It now works I think, I first removed the dependencies then connected to the database, then added it back and synced the gradle again
